# Spring Data MongoDB GridFS images are corrupted when getting with contentType

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, gridfs

I'm trying to store and retrieve images with GridFs using Spring.

**Method for uploading 1:**

```
public void savePicture(InputStream photo, Customer customer) {

        Query query = new Query (Criteria.where("filename").is(customer.getId()).and("metadata.status").is("active"));

        Update update = new Update().set("metadata.status" , "false");

        WriteResult wr = this.mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "fs.files");

        if (!wr.getLastConcern().callGetLastError()){

        DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
        metaData.put("status", "active");

        String imageFormat = this.imageUtils.getImageFormat(photo);

        String contentType = "image/" + imageFormat;

        GridFSFile gridFsFile = this.gridFsTemplate.store(photo, customer.getId(), contentType, metaData);

        }

    }
```

**Method for uploading 2 (differs only when invoking this.gridFsTemplage.store)**

```
public void saveProfilePicture(InputStream photo, Customer customer) {

        Query query = new Query (Criteria.where("filename").is(customer.getId()).and("metadata.status").is("active"));

        Update update = new Update().set("metadata.status" , "false");

        WriteResult wr = this.mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, "fs.files");

        if (!wr.getLastConcern().callGetLastError()){

        DBObject metaData = new BasicDBObject();
        metaData.put("status", "active");

        GridFSFile gridFsFile = this.gridFsTemplate.store(photo, customer.getId(), metaData);

        }

    }
```

**Method for downloading:**

```
public InputStream getPicture(Customer customer){

        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("filename").is(customer.getId()).and("metadata.status").is("active"));

        GridFSDBFile gridFsDBFile = this.gridFsTemplate.findOne(query);

        return gridFsDBFile.getInputStream();

    }
```

Both methods for uploading work and write on MongoDB/GridFS, but when I use method 1 I cannot download the picture and it appears to be corrupted. For example if I upload a picture of 7.8KB the downloaded version is ligther of 500 bytes (7.3KB) and I cannot open it with an image viewer. 
When I use the method 2 for upload everything works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you run this on MongoShell , you can see gridfs files: `db.fs.files.find()`
Now, the problem in your method 1 is that you are not specifying the full name of the file.(If
you dont specify the full name i.e filename + extension)

```
GridFSFile gridFsFile = this.gridFsTemplate.store(photo, customer.getId(), contentType, metaData);
Should be changed to=>
GridFSFile gridFsFile = this.gridFsTemplate.store(photo, customer.getId() + "." + imageFormat, contentType, metaData);
```

Comment: But in this case how do I know what is the file extension when I query the db? (I'm assuming that I could store different image formats of course)

Comment: Exactly, if you want to store images with different formats go for method 2.. :)

Comment: :) ok but in that case I cannot fill the contentType field, that I don't think is strictly needed in my case (right now at least) but I think is strange that I cannot fill it :-/

Comment: Correct, method 2 is suitable for your use case. Hope the code trick helped.